# Within Low Quality Posts review, indicate when answer author is also question author

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts

### EDIT 7th Aug 15

[NathanTuggy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/274165/nathan-tuggy) brought to my attention that the small area surrounding the *username; Timestamp; Gravatar; Rep; Badge count* is actually already highlighted when the answer author in the review queue is also the question author where the answer is from.
(Same as normal threads do when question author answers.)

As such, no need for this feature.

Being more familiar to author highlighting on comments, where the username becomes quite prominent, in the review queue I looked right at the username and missed the highlight spanning further afield.
(I'll take my slap from Bruce, I missed all that [heavenly glory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=4O9o4CKTGzQ#t=74)...)

(end edit)

---

In the Low Quality Posts review area, it would be really useful if there could be some indication *within the review area* when the author of the answer in the review is also the author of the question of where the answer is from.

This would help speed up the process in identifying if the question author has answered to provide more info (and should have been an edit) or if something else is happening.

---

The site seems to already know if author of the answer in the review is also the question author, as one of the "recommend delete" options change.

When the answer author is *also* the question author, the delete option:

> This is an "I’m having this problem, too" comment

Is replaced with:

> This answer should be an edit to the question

So I'm guessing/hoping this won't be too much work.

---

Sometimes it *seems* like the question author has answered, based on the answer content and/or comments. But it's not always obvious, such as:
"Thanks for the info, I tried XYZ but couldn't get it to work".
It's not obvious if this is the question author answering to add info, or another user trying to ask for additional info.

So to review correctly, I have to check by going to the answer and scrolling up to the question to see if it's the same user as the one in the review.
This isn't ideal as I have to carefully check usernames for similarities, and even then (however unlikely) it could be different users with the same username.

I could just view the "Recommend delete" options and see if the option has changed to show "should be an edit to the question", but this also isn't ideal because when the answer author is *not* the question author I have to backtrack and re-evaluate the review.

But neither way is ideal to manage reviewing, and I really want the info I need to review to be within the review area.

I can then immediately see if the answer author is question author or not and review accordingly, and more quickly.

---

I know this sounds trivial, and might sound rare, but given the thousands of reviews and reviewers, I believe this would actually be quite a helpful addition and used a quite a bit.

Comment: Doesn't the answer username highlight do the job here?

Comment: @nathan it certainly would, if it did.

Comment: It [works for me](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9074901).

Comment: @nathan Nope I still don't see the username is highlighted in the review area.

Comment: Looks like this is a bug or possibly browser defect, because it's certainly doing things just fine for me... and I don't have a userscript filling that in, either.

Comment: I see a perfectly good highlight on the question and self-answer. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: The entire user info (gravatar and all) is within a `<td class="post-signature owner" align="right">` in review and on the self-answer.

Comment: Ok, I apologise for wasting your time. I realise now the entire username/ asked timestamp/profile image/etc is wrapped in a blue background. I was just looking at the username (as per our comments) and seeing past the larger area. Additionally, my LCD monitor sits low down, and so the highlight wasn't visible. (Any higher or lower and it would have been shown.) So yes, I guess this feature request is redundant.

Comment: Awesome, looks like we're good to go.